# RESTful way to specify commands on a resource

Tags: rest

I could not find a universally agreeable way to specify commands in RESTful manner. Consider that I have a resource on which I want to provide 3 commands:

- enable
- disable
- re-trigger

Which is the most RESTful way?

1. `POST /resource/disable`
2. `POST /resource?command=disable`
3. Any other way ?

Answer (score -1):

> Which is the most RESTful way?

How would you do it with a web site?  [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5) of the world wide web; if you can figure out how you would do it with a web site, that will give you the right idea for how to provide a RESTful API.

On the web, the usual answer would be that we would have *forms* to collect information from the client, who would then submit a `POST` request (because we are intending to change the resource) to some endpoint.

Because the `form.action` property tells the client what URI to use, the server has control over what the URI is -- we can change it later if we want to.

We could, as you suggest, have a different URI for each command.  There's nothing wrong with that, but it does miss an opportunity.  You see, one of the important ideas in REST is caching; and HTTP defines [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) semantics; the practical aspect of which is that if you use the `/resource` identifier as the form action, then successful `POST` requests will automatically invalidate the client's local copies of the resource.

This does imply, of course, that the `POST` handler in your implementation will have to determine which command was intended -- probably by looking at information included in the body of the post request; a "commandName" parameter or something similar.